# How to continue processing after return result from asp.net core controller method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I have some process that take long processing time that client not need the response immediately. I've tried below code without success.

```cs
    [HttpPost, Route("run")]
    public async Task Run()
    {
        _ = this.LongProcess().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

The service still take time until my LongProces finish before return to the client.
How can I make the Run method return to the client promptly ?

Comment: The async C# feature isn't meant to allow you to continue processing after you've returned from your method. What you want to achieve is an asynchronous workflow, but you can't achieve it with the async C# feature. First, you need to decide whether it makes sense to do this work within a web application, or whether it makes more sense to do it elsewhere. Web servers are good at handling HTTP requests. They're not good for background processing. They have limited threads, are subject to idle shutdowns and random app pool restarts etc.

Comment: What might make more sense is to move your long running processing into a dedicated background service (perhaps using a Windows Service app, an Azure Function/AWS Lambda, or some other form of background work). Then your web app can accept the job details via an HTTP request, and enqueue that work somehow (perhaps using a database table, RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus, AWS SQS etc). Your background processing service would then pick up the job details from that enqueued work and process it, perhaps sending our a notification when it's done.

Comment: For the record, I ended up using this package for my project. https://github.com/DalSoft/DalSoft.Hosting.BackgroundQueue Works really well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I make the Run method return to the client promptly?

You need a basic distributed architecture. [I recommend](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html):

1. A durable storage system, such as Azure Queues or AWS Simple Queue Service.
2. An independent processor, such as Azure Functions or AWS Lambdas.

Then, your API enqueues the message and returns:

```
[HttpPost, Route("run")]
public async Task Run()
{
  var message = new Message();
  await _queueService.EnqueueAsync(message);
  return;
}
```

and the independent processor dequeues messages and handles them:

```
async Task HandleMessage(Message message)
{
  await LongProcess().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```